# Preloaded gestures on Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, gesture

I'm wondering if there are any preloaded gestures on kivy, such as pinch, expand, etc. The examples have check, square, circle, and cross gestures. Is there a database for more?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is, not many people use the gestures. We have a gsoc project that will probably bring some improved tools for this to kivy core, though.

Comment: what would you recommend for user input? I would like a interactive interface and thought that gestures would be good.